# SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: items.title: INSERT INTO "items" ("image", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, null, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a simple app where a user can add a subject to a cart. But there is an error about not null constraint.

The error message browser shows is like that.

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: items.title: INSERT INTO "items" ("image", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)

I've tried deleting not null constraint in `schema.rb`. But the error message is still on. So, what should I do?

Schema:

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "image", null: false
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.string "description", null: false
    t.string "stock", null: false
    t.string "price", null: false
    t.integer "status", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Controller:

```
class SellController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def confirm
  @item = Item.new(title: params[:title],price: params[:price],stock: params[:stock],description: params[:description],image: "default_item.jpg")
  render :new if @item.invalid?
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(title: params[:title],price: params[:price],stock: params[:stock],description: params[:description],image: "default_item.jpg")
    #@item = Item.new(item_params)
    if params[:image]
      @item.image = "#{@item.id}.jpg" 
      image = params[:image]
      File.binwrite("public/item_images/#{@item.image}", image.read)
    end
    if params[:back]
      format.html { render :new }
    elsif @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "your item data is saved."
      redirect_to("/sell/complete")
    else
      render("sell/new")
    end
  end

  def complete
  end
end
```

I expect item data be saved and the page on browser is changed to thanks page.

Comment: try fill your datetime, created_at & updated_at

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at your error message:

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: items.title: INSERT INTO "items" ("image", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)

It says that failed not null constraint on `items.title` column. And indeed, you don't provide `title` in your insert statement. It means that they were not passed to `Item.new` in your controller code.

I can see two solutions - if you want to keep all those constraints (you have multiple not-null columns in your table), you should also add active record `presence` validations. They will prevent calling `insert` statement to the database if values are missing and they will give you nice error messages in `@item.error`.

If you can allow those columns to be nullable, you can drop the constraint in a migration:

```
change_column_null :items, :title, false
```

You can also rollback the migration that created `items` table and edit this migration to avoid setting `NOT NULL` constraint there.

`schema.rb` is generated when you run migrations and can be used to load schema into a database. It's not done automatically though, you need to run a proper rake task (`rake db:schema:load`). It's not advisable to edit this file manually, as it's auto-generated and your changes will be automatically overwritten.